# Laravel @yield in code php

Tags: php, laravel, image-size

How I can get content from `@yield` in PHP?

Example I have in app.blade.php:

```
@yield('image-url', asset('/img/metaog.png?2'))
```

I want getimagesize from image-url:

```
<?php 
    $image = getimagesize(yield('image-url', asset('/img/metaog.png?2')));
    $width = $image[0];
    $height = $image[1];
?>
```

How I can get this correctly? My code is not working.

Comment: Seems like you don't understand what is `@yield` for.

Comment: Why would you want to get the content from the `@yield` directive?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Laravel 5.5 and up:

```
View::getSection('image-url', 'your default value')
```

In Laravel 5.4 and below:

```
View::getSections()['image-url']
```

That will get what was assigned to that named section. You will have to do your check to see if it has anything still. If using the first method you should be checking if that array key actually exists.

You can use `View::hasSection(...)` to check if the section exists at all, if needed.

Comment: This is not working. I have laravel 5.5. I get null. URL section he see, but image-url - not.

Comment: if you get a `null`, that section wasn't set, or its empty ... updated to include default argument to `getSection`

Comment: In Laravel 10.x (year 2023) it still works