# Laravel Blade Conditional @Yield

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a blade view which makes use of my template using

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

Within that template I want to show 2 buttons if the section on my child view is true, rather than having to include them in every child view that makes use of the template.

**For example, my layout (snippet)**

```
@yield('buttons')
  <div>
    <button>BUTTON 1</button>
    <button>BUTTON 2</button>
  </div>
@show 

@yield('content)
```

**Here's my child view**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('buttons',false)

@section('content')
  <p>Hello world!</p>
@endsection
```

I know it doesn't work the way I've tried but is something like this possible? I've also tried wrapping the @yield('buttons') in an @if but this isn't possible as @yield can only be used in a function apparently.

Comment: "Within that template I want to show 2 buttons if true", if what is true?

Comment: @SapneshNaik if in my child view the value I pass is true.. @section('buttons',false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - @yield() not allowed in if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957840/laravel-yield-not-allowed-in-if)

Comment: What's wrong with including them?

Comment: I've figured it out.. I'll delete the question

Comment: Why not post the solution here for others to see?

Comment: @kerbholz done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within in my master layout I replace @yield with @section

```
@section('buttons')

  <button>BUTTON 1</button>
  <button>BUTTON 2</button>

@endsection
```

**Within my child view I use**

```
@section('buttons','')
```

This replaces the default, if you wish to keep the default and place your additional content before or after then use @parent before or after your additional content for example in my child view:

```
@section('buttons')
   Additional content to be inserted before the buttons in my master layout.
   @parent
@endsection
```

**Outputs:**

Additional content to be inserted before the buttons in my master layout. BUTTON 1BUTTON 2

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade